# Finding a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a project and I need to find ALL paths to a specific file name

currently, I have some code that is working

```
    for r, d, f in os.walk(roaming):
      for file in f:
          if filename in file:
              file_paths.append(os.path.join(r))
```

However, I am running into an issue If the code finds the specific file name it stops there it does not keep searching the directory for the file for instance

first_folder contains 2 items findme and second_folder

second_folder contains 1 item findme

currently it will return first_folder\findme if I search for findme

I want it to return first_folder\findme and first_folder\second_folder\findme
I have seen the use of glob.glob but cant seem to get it to work with files without an extension. I can get it to work with a .txt or a .HTML but if the file does not have an extension I cant seem to find it

Comment: Doesn't make sense. What is your root directory?

Answer (score 0):

you can open/find a specific file using the ff code, just try :)

```
    def browse(self):
        fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select a file...", filter="All files (*)")
        if fileName != '':
            self.entryFileName.setText(str(fileName))  
            self.writeAttendance()
```